# how can i use if statement in video view if the video not work

Tags: java, android, video, uri, android-videoview

in my java code , i have VideoView and im parsing the video to him in URI From internet(i set link of video) , but after 6 Hours , they are changed the link of video , and if the old link of video has still in uri he giving me message "Can't play this video" , but now ho can i use `if` statement and i set inside it nearly 7 link of video and if the first link of video converted to doesn't  work .. automatically he chose the second link of video .
it is a impossible ?
my code :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("myVideoLink");

    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void play(String[] videoUrls, final int current) {
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrls[current]));
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
            try {
                // try to play video from next video url
                play(videoUrls, current + 1);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                // end is reached
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    videoView.start();
}
```

For start playing

```
play(new String[]{"url1", "url2"}, 0);
```